# How to fetch same inputField with different lables in VisualForce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforcedx, visualforce-component, user-interface

I have an object "Details_Page__c" which has a lookup field "Next_Change__c" associated with it. The object is initialized in my controller class  -

```
Details_Page__c detailsPage = new Details_Page__c();
```

I want to show this field twice in my visualforce page once with the original label and once with a custom label. In VF page -

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">
     <apex:inputField value="{!detailsPage.Next_Change__c}" />
     <apex:inputField value="{!detailsPage.Next_Change__c}" label="Previous Change" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The user is allowed to select different lookup values for these fields from the VF page. However, I want to be able to fetch the values of these fields with separate labels in my controller class and use those separately for different purposes. I know I can fetch the value like -

```
Next_Change__c nextChange = detailsPage.Next_Change__c;
```

My question is how do I also read the field with the custom label "Previous Change" ?

```
Next_Change__c previousChange = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be pretty simple. Just initialized the same object in the controller with another name along with the existing one.

```
Details_Page__c detailsPage = new Details_Page__c();    
Details_Page__c detailsPagePrevious = new Details_Page__c();
```

And referred the same field for this object in the VF page and used that field's value again in the controller

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">
     <apex:inputField value="{!detailsPage.Next_Change__c}" />
     <apex:inputField value="{!detailsPagePrevious.Next_Change__c}" label="Previous Change" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And finally in my controller, used it for my case like -

```
Next_Change__c nextChange = detailsPage.Next_Change__c;
Next_Change__c previousChange = detailsPagePrevious.Next_Change__c;
```